# Creating a context-free grammar for a given language

Tags: context-free-grammar

I am given the language

```
{b a^m1 ba^m2 ba^m3 .... ba^mn | n >= 2, m1,...,mn >= 0, and mi != mj for some i.j}
```

That is, it strings with beginning with a b and at least 2 b's and somewhere a different number of a's between them. E.g., "bab", "bba", "bbba", "babbab",... but not "bb", "baba", "babaaba",...

How can I create a CFG for this language.

I already have something the following but I can't seem to make it complete it for more than 2 b's; I'm also not so sure if my general approach is correct.

```
 S -> bAbaA | baAbA.
 A -> aaA  | ε.
```

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to do is apply the pumping lemma for CFGs and make sure that is a CFG.  First glance looks like it may not be.

Comment: The task was to find a CFG and pushdown automata so I assumed it was a context free language.

Comment: Also using the pumping lemma I can't find a decomposition such that it contradicts the pumping lemma.

Comment: @Christaline, never take that sort of thing for granted. Sometimes its a trick question, sometimes the instructor is just wrong.  I know -- it's happened to me, both ways.